# Remove additional column from Exporting to Excel from SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a two Matrix Report Items with different DataSet same number of columns and rows of result. matrix table 1 is on the left side and the other one is on the other side, there are no spaces between the two table in design view.

The problem is after exporting to excel between the Matrix Report Items it creates additional column in Excel. How can i avoid this?

http://www.4shared.com/download/6w5JljQu/Sample.jpg

Comment: Does your table on the left side have less than 4 columns? I tried to imitate your problem, and if the first table has less than 4 columns, after export to excel, there is merged column. However when I add one more column to the left side table, after export there is no additional column (I'm using SSRS 2010).

Comment: As I said I think this is SSRS bug. Can you add to the first table 3 columns (even empty) and then try to export to excel and check if there is this additional column?

Comment: I checked this case on my examplary report. When I manually change the width (by typing width in properties window) to at least 3 cm, after exporting to excel the additional column disapeared. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I already tried with the solution of your's Konza but still didn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is common problem in SSRS - the way how I removing this problem is to use rectangle's . Insert rectangle then CUT your table/matrix PASTE inside rectangle - make sure there is not empty spaces. If you using more than one table/matrix , then insert rectangle inside rectangle etc. ( my record is 14-th depth ) - this is VERY annoying but I know only this way.

Comment: Daniel thank you for answering about this issue in SSRS bug ...I tried with your solution and did work fine to me ..thanks daniel ...I will post again later if I encounter some new error that I can't solve by myself...THANKS :)